# signtool fail with inno setup : 0x80070003 - "Store IsDiskFile() failed"

Tags: inno-setup, signtool

I'm getting a weird error whiles signing my software. I'm using inno setup 4.5.2.

```
Running Sign Tool command: signtool.exe sign /a /f cert.pfx /v /t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" /p pwd /d "Setup Label" "out\uninst.e32.tmp"
SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
Error information: "Error: Store IsDiskFile() failed." (-2147024893/0x80070003)
Error in W:\path\installer.iss: Sign Tool failed with exit code 0x1.
Compile aborted.
```

Command line seems pretty ok, it even work outside the inno setup compile. While setting the `SignedUninstaller=no` get me farther, it still make this error while trying to sign the output setup file.

Now i've looked pretty much everywhere for that error code (0x80070003) and/or the message "Store IsDiskFile() failed". I have also tried with multiple version of signtool.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I figured out the problem, the path to the certificate must be relative to the installer output path, not the current working folder. In this case, it would be "..\cert.pfx".

Comment: This message indicates the certificate file can't be found. In my case, it was just plain missing (not checked out locally). +1

Comment: Well in my case it was the path to the _file to be signed_ that was incorrect. In any case, this post pointed me in the right direction, but yeah, the error message could be better!

Comment: In my case I needed to change the certificate path from relative to absolute (within my ci build server's workspace).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. My problem was I have used `"` in the `signTool` command, while I needed to use `$q` instead. Surprisingly it was successfully signed the executable but it failed to sign the result setup.exe file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had the wrong Path for the certificate file. A message like "pfx not found" would much be better than just "IsDiskFile() failed."....

Answer (score 0):

My problem was having the .pfx file on a network drive (G:). Moving it to a lokal drive (C:) solved the problem.