# Signtool "Store IsDiskFile() failed. 0x80070003"

Tags: batch-file, code-signing, signtool

I am currently trying to automate the signing of executables via a .bat script

The following code is within the script:

```
@echo off
color 0A
set CERTIFICATE_PATH=Certs\Pfx\cert.pfx
set CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD=My-Pw
set TIMESTAMP_URL=http://timestamp.digicert.com

set PROJECT_OUTPUT_PATH=%1

signtool sign /f "%CERTIFICATE_PATH%" /p "%CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD%" /t %TIMESTAMP_URL% /fd SHA256 /v "%PROJECT_OUTPUT_PATH%"
```

My file structure is the following:

This is the path to the file I want to sign: `C:\1A\test.exe`

This is the path to the script: `C:\2A\SignScript.bat`

The certificate is in a subfolder of the script path itself and is saved here: `C:\2A\Certs\Pfx\cert.pfx`

Now when I execute the script with this command: `C:\2A\SignScript.bat "C:\1A\test.exe"`

I get the following error:

> SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred. Error
> information: "Error: Store IsDiskFile() failed."
> (-2147024893/0x80070003)

I don't get what the problem is to be honest. The paths seem fine to me and signing it with a third party app (which uses signing tool as well" works too...

**EDIT:** I've tried to **do it by hand** in order to rule out any problems with the certificate and such. Entering the command  `signtool sign /f "cert.pfx" /p "My-Pw" /t "http://timestamp.digicert.com" /fd SHA256 /v C:\1A\test.exe` while using the command prompt inside the folder of the certificate works without any problems and signs my application! So at least there are not any problems with the certificate...

**EDIT2:** I have also tried the proposed solution of @Stephan from the comments but unfortunately it does not work and I still get the same error.

Comment: Problem with quoting. `%1` is quoted, so `PROJECT_OUTPUT_PATH` has quotes, and you quote it again with the `signtool` line. Switch to `set PROJECT_OUTPUT_PATH=%~1` to remove the quotes from the argument or even better `set "PROJECT_OUTPUT_PATH=%~1"` (recommended syntax, the quotes makes it safe against stray spaces and "poison chars" and are not included in the variable name or value)

Comment: @Stephan I just tried it again with only ``C:\1A\test.exe`` and no quotes and it still throws the same error. I have also tried to use your recommended solution for the set command and it fails as well with the same error. I don't think the quotes are the problem.

Comment: `... /v ""C:\1A\test.exe""` *should* be a problem (obviously not your only one)). Run with `echo on` and compare the executed script command with your manual command. Any differences should give you a clue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655287/signtool-fail-with-inno-setup-0x80070003-store-isdiskfile-failed says that that particular error code means "cert file not found." I suggest trying full paths instead of relative paths.

Comment: @SomethingDark This seems to be it. For some reason it does not allow a relative path  for the certificate. Just changed it to the full Path ```C:\2A\Certs\Pfx\cert.pfx`` and it works....